# Method for optimally packing a group of squares from (1 x 1) to (n x n) into a larger square?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, packing-problem

As far as my investigation has gone, I can see that people have worked on the optimal way to pack [incrementally larger squares into rectangles](https://www.jair.org/media/3735/live-3735-6794-jair.pdf) (page 2, .pdf), as well as the optimal ways to pack [equal squares into a square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_packing_in_a_square). I have not, however, found a reasonable algorithm or method for packing incrementally larger (or smaller, depending on your point of view) squares into a larger square area. It feels similar to the first link, but with additional constraints on the rectangle container.

As an example of what I am asking about, I manually created a packing of a group of squares (1x1, 2x2, 3x3,...8x8) in a "square" container. Is this something that has been researched at all, or is it largely just a meaningless corner case (ha!) of packing squares into a rectangle?

Since I have just joined this stack, I cannot embed my image, but it can be found here: [image: packing of integer squares]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A005842](http://oeis.org/A005842)

You can buy it at [Kadon Enterprises](http://www.gamepuzzles.com/37square.htm)

I posted various solutions on [2 March 2003](http://www.mathpuzzle.com/26Mar03.html).  The most recent imporovement I know about was Shigeyoshi Kamakura's packing of 23 squares into 66x66, in 2004.

[image: Shigeyoshi Kamakura's pack of 23 squares]

More solutions are posted [here](http://www.geocities.co.jp/Berkeley-Labo/6317/seqsqr_00.htm).  Many of the solutions were found by Robert Reid. There is also the [Oct 99 Math Magic](https://erich-friedman.github.io/mathmagic/1099.html).

Comment: Oh, this is amazing! Thank you!